# I add a product into a product list, but this product is showed only after I reload the page.How can I solved this problem?

Tags: angular

I open a pop-up for adding a product into a product-list, after a click the submit button(this button makes a post request to backend) I want to show me the old list of items but also the mew product added. The added product is shown just after i reload the page. How can I solved this problem?

Comment: It would be nice if you add your code into your question so that everyone can track and help you where you are facing to the issue

Comment: Yeah there's a lot of potential answers here.  Code would be helpful.  One possible solution is to have your pop up return the new object that was created when it close and then add it to your list.  Another option is to just do a full reload when the pop-up closes.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the object of product you added when you close the pop up or fetch the list of products once you close the pop up .